# Using a character as a starting and ending point for a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, text-parsing

So I have a text file like this

1 5 8
D 3 5 7 8
D 4 6 7 8 9
D 2
D 2 4 7 9 8 5

What I've been trying to do is have the scanner read until it sees the first 'D' then process all the numbers that follow until it hits the second 'D' The problem with this the next time the scanner looks for a starting point it will be at the third 'D'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the current state of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could let [the **Scanner** use "D" as the `delimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1 5 8 D 3 5 7 8 D 4 6 7 8 9 D 2 D 2 4 7 9 8 5";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("D");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        sc.next(); // "1 5 8", "3 5 7 8", ...
    }
}
```

It is not clear if you want to skip the leading numbers, but if you want to do that, just call next() once before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can even do it this way

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    new FileInputStream("something.txt") ));
while(true){
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if(line==null)
        break;
    else{
        String arr[] = line.split("d");
        // arr contains 1 5 8 at 0 index 3 5 7  at index 1 and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several options, here are 3 :

1) Using a Reader and checking every character :

```
Reader in = ...; // Obtain an instance, likely getting an InputStream and a CharSet.
CharArrayWriter buffer = new CharArrayWriter();
while (in.ready) { // Safe because you said you're reading from a File
    char c = in.read();
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        char[] lastRead = buffer.toCharArray();
        buffer.reset();
    } else {
        buffer.append(c);
    }
}
```

2) Using `String.split` function. This method requires that you read fully the file prior into a `String`

```
String[] parts = myFileContent.split("[a-zA-Z]");
```

3) Using a `StringTokenizer` that provides then an `Enumeration` of the strings found. This requires too that you read the content of the whole `File` first.

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(myFileContent, "abc....Z"); // The construction of the set of delimiters can be automatized with a loop over a char for example.
while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String somePart = str.nextToken();
}
```